# Blogger auto resize thumbnail image

Tags: blogger

I use sora shop template, on the main page the slider image automatically resizes 72px, I want the image to display at default. thank's.

[image: image was resize]

Comment: Are you using the free version of the theme or have you purchased it? if it is free version you need to add additional javascript.  If you let me know, I will try to help.

Comment: i use premium version on internet.

Comment: You should add the javascript codes of the theme so that we can edit it.

Comment: Did you solved this issue?